# CentOS 8 - XRDP cannot login for the second time

Tags: centos, rdp, xrdp

Somehow I cannot connect with RDP for the second time to CentOS 8 running xRDP.

I tried changing KillDisconnected in sesman.ini to true without success.

I Use xrdp with the following settings:

/etc/xrdp.ini

```
; xrdp.ini file version number
ini_version=1

; fork a new process for each incoming connection
fork=true

; ports to listen on, number alone means listen on all interfaces
; 0.0.0.0 or :: if ipv6 is configured
; space between multiple occurrences
;
; Examples:
;   port=3389
;   port=unix://./tmp/xrdp.socket
;   port=tcp://.:3389                           127.0.0.1:3389
;   port=tcp://:3389                            *:3389
;   port=tcp://<any ipv4 format addr>:3389      192.168.1.1:3389
;   port=tcp6://.:3389                          ::1:3389
;   port=tcp6://:3389                           *:3389
;   port=tcp6://{<any ipv6 format addr>}:3389   {FC00:0:0:0:0:0:0:1}:3389
;   port=vsock://<cid>:<port>
port=3389

; 'port' above should be connected to with vsock instead of tcp
; use this only with number alone in port above
; prefer use vsock://<cid>:<port> above
use_vsock=false

; regulate if the listening socket use socket option tcp_nodelay
; no buffering will be performed in the TCP stack
tcp_nodelay=true

; regulate if the listening socket use socket option keepalive
; if the network connection disappear without close messages the connection will be closed
tcp_keepalive=true

; set tcp send/recv buffer (for experts)
#tcp_send_buffer_bytes=32768
#tcp_recv_buffer_bytes=32768

; security layer can be 'tls', 'rdp' or 'negotiate'
; for client compatible layer
security_layer=negotiate

; minimum security level allowed for client for classic RDP encryption
; use tls_ciphers to configure TLS encryption
; can be 'none', 'low', 'medium', 'high', 'fips'
crypt_level=high

; X.509 certificate and private key
; openssl req -x509 -newkey rsa:2048 -nodes -keyout key.pem -out cert.pem -days 365
certificate=
key_file=

; set SSL protocols
; can be comma separated list of 'SSLv3', 'TLSv1', 'TLSv1.1', 'TLSv1.2', 'TLSv1.3'
ssl_protocols=TLSv1.2, TLSv1.3
; set TLS cipher suites
#tls_ciphers=HIGH

; Section name to use for automatic login if the client sends username
; and password. If empty, the domain name sent by the client is used.
; If empty and no domain name is given, the first suitable section in
; this file will be used.
autorun=

allow_channels=true
allow_multimon=true
bitmap_cache=true
bitmap_compression=true
bulk_compression=true
#hidelogwindow=true
max_bpp=32
new_cursors=true
; fastpath - can be 'input', 'output', 'both', 'none'
use_fastpath=both
; when true, userid/password *must* be passed on cmd line
#require_credentials=true
; You can set the PAM error text in a gateway setup (MAX 256 chars)
#pamerrortxt=change your password according to policy at http://url

;
; colors used by windows in RGB format
;
blue=009cb5
grey=dedede
#black=000000
#dark_grey=808080
#blue=08246b
#dark_blue=08246b
#white=ffffff
#red=ff0000
#green=00ff00
#background=626c72

;
; configure login screen
;

; Login Screen Window Title
#ls_title=My Login Title

; top level window background color in RGB format
ls_top_window_bg_color=009cb5

; width and height of login screen
ls_width=350
ls_height=430

; login screen background color in RGB format
ls_bg_color=dedede

; optional background image filename (bmp format).
#ls_background_image=

; logo
; full path to bmp-file or file in shared folder
ls_logo_filename=
ls_logo_x_pos=55
ls_logo_y_pos=50

; for positioning labels such as username, password etc
ls_label_x_pos=30
ls_label_width=65

; for positioning text and combo boxes next to above labels
ls_input_x_pos=110
ls_input_width=210

; y pos for first label and combo box
ls_input_y_pos=220

; OK button
ls_btn_ok_x_pos=142
ls_btn_ok_y_pos=370
ls_btn_ok_width=85
ls_btn_ok_height=30

; Cancel button
ls_btn_cancel_x_pos=237
ls_btn_cancel_y_pos=370
ls_btn_cancel_width=85
ls_btn_cancel_height=30

[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=true
SyslogLevel=DEBUG
; LogLevel and SysLogLevel could by any of: core, error, warning, info or debug

[Channels]
; Channel names not listed here will be blocked by XRDP.
; You can block any channel by setting its value to false.
; IMPORTANT! All channels are not supported in all use
; cases even if you set all values to true.
; You can override these settings on each session type
; These settings are only used if allow_channels=true
rdpdr=true
rdpsnd=true
drdynvc=true
cliprdr=true
rail=true
xrdpvr=true
tcutils=true

; for debugging xrdp, in section xrdp1, change port=-1 to this:
#port=/tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_display_10

; for debugging xrdp, add following line to section xrdp1
#chansrvport=/tmp/.xrdp/xrdp_chansrv_socket_7210


;
; Session types
;

; Some session types such as Xorg, X11rdp and Xvnc start a display server.
; Startup command-line parameters for the display server are configured
; in sesman.ini. See and configure also sesman.ini.
#[Xorg]
#name=Xorg
#lib=libxup.so
#username=ask
#password=ask
#ip=127.0.0.1
#port=-1
#code=20

[Xvnc]
name=Xvnc
lib=libvnc.so
username=ask
password=ask
ip=127.0.0.1
port=-1
#xserverbpp=24
#delay_ms=2000

#[vnc-any]
#name=vnc-any
#lib=libvnc.so
#ip=ask
#port=ask5900
#username=na
#password=ask
#pamusername=asksame
#pampassword=asksame
#pamsessionmng=127.0.0.1
#delay_ms=2000

#[neutrinordp-any]
#name=neutrinordp-any
#lib=libxrdpneutrinordp.so
#ip=ask
#port=ask3389
#username=ask
#password=ask

; You can override the common channel settings for each session type
#channel.rdpdr=true
#channel.rdpsnd=true
#channel.drdynvc=true
#channel.cliprdr=true
#channel.rail=true
#channel.xrdpvr=true
```

/etc/xrdp/sesman.ini

```
;; See `man 5 sesman.ini` for details

[Globals]
ListenAddress=127.0.0.1
ListenPort=3350
EnableUserWindowManager=true
; Give in relative path to user's home directory
UserWindowManager=startwm.sh
; Give in full path or relative path to /etc/xrdp
DefaultWindowManager=startwm-bash.sh
; Give in full path or relative path to /etc/xrdp
ReconnectScript=reconnectwm.sh

[Security]
AllowRootLogin=true
MaxLoginRetry=4
TerminalServerUsers=tsusers
TerminalServerAdmins=tsadmins
; When AlwaysGroupCheck=false access will be permitted
; if the group TerminalServerUsers is not defined.
AlwaysGroupCheck=false
; When RestrictOutboundClipboard=true clipboard from the
; server is not pushed to the client.
RestrictOutboundClipboard=false

[Sessions]
;; X11DisplayOffset - x11 display number offset
; Type: integer
; Default: 10
X11DisplayOffset=10

;; MaxSessions - maximum number of connections to an xrdp server
; Type: integer
; Default: 0
MaxSessions=50

;; KillDisconnected - kill disconnected sessions
; Type: boolean
; Default: false
; if 1, true, or yes, kill session after 60 seconds
KillDisconnected=false

;; DisconnectedTimeLimit - when to kill idle sessions
; Type: integer
; Default: 0
; if not zero, the seconds before a disconnected session is killed
; min 60 seconds
DisconnectedTimeLimit=0

;; IdleTimeLimit (specify in second) - wait before disconnect idle sessions
; Type: integer
; Default: 0
; Set to 0 to disable idle disconnection.
IdleTimeLimit=0

;; Policy - session allocation policy
; Type: enum [ "Default" | "UBD" | "UBI" | "UBC" | "UBDI" | "UBDC" ]
; Default: Xrdp:<User,BitPerPixel> and Xvnc:<User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize>
; "UBD" session per <User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize>
; "UBI" session per <User,BitPerPixel,IPAddr>
; "UBC" session per <User,BitPerPixel,Connection>
; "UBDI" session per <User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize,IPAddr>
; "UBDC" session per <User,BitPerPixel,DisplaySize,Connection>
Policy=Default

[Logging]
LogFile=xrdp-sesman.log
LogLevel=DEBUG
EnableSyslog=1
SyslogLevel=DEBUG

;
; Session definitions - startup command-line parameters for each session type
;

[Xorg]
; Specify the path of non-suid Xorg executable. It might differ depending
; on your distribution and version. The typical path is shown as follows:
;
; Fedora 26 or later    :  param=/usr/libexec/Xorg
; Debian 9 or later     :  param=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
; Ubuntu 16.04 or later :  param=/usr/lib/xorg/Xorg
; Arch Linux            :  param=/usr/lib/xorg-server/Xorg
; CentOS 7              :  param=/usr/bin/Xorg or param=Xorg
;
param=Xorg
; Leave the rest paramaters as-is unless you understand what will happen.
param=-config
param=xrdp/xorg.conf
param=-noreset
param=-nolisten
param=tcp
param=-logfile
param=.xorgxrdp.%s.log

[Xvnc]
param=Xvnc
param=-bs
param=-nolisten
param=tcp
param=-localhost
param=-dpi
param=96

[Chansrv]
; drive redirection, defaults to xrdp_client if not set
FuseMountName=thinclient_drives
; this value allows only the user to acess their own mapped drives.
; Make this more permissive (e.g. 022) if required.
FileUmask=077

[SessionVariables]
PULSE_SCRIPT=/etc/xrdp/pulse/default.pa
```

Lines added to log when trying to connect:

```
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: postBeta2ColorDepth 0xca01 (0xca00 4bpp 0xca01 8bpp 0xca02 15bpp 0xca03 16bpp 0xca04 24bpp)
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: highColorDepth 0x0010 (0x0004 4bpp 0x0008 8bpp 0x000f 15bpp 0x0010 16 bpp 0x0018 24bpp)
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: supportedColorDepths 0x000f (0x0001 24bpp 0x0002 16bpp 0x0004 15bpp 0x0008 32bpp)
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: earlyCapabilityFlags 0x07ad (0x0002 want32)
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: got client client connection type 0x00000007
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_sec_process_mcs_data_CS_SECURITY:
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]:  client supports 40 bit encryption
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]:  client supports 128 bit encryption
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]:  client supports 56 bit encryption
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]:  client supports fips encryption
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: [20201123-11:23:13] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpdr chan_id 1004 flags 0x80800000
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: [20201123-11:23:13] [INFO ] adding channel item name rdpsnd chan_id 1005 flags 0xc0000000
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: [20201123-11:23:13] [INFO ] adding channel item name cliprdr chan_id 1006 flags 0xc0a00000
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: [20201123-11:23:13] [INFO ] adding channel item name nlr3hv chan_id 1007 flags 0x84200000
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: [20201123-11:23:13] [INFO ] adding channel item name nlw3hv chan_id 1008 flags 0x84200000
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: [20201123-11:23:13] [INFO ] adding channel item name drdynvc chan_id 1009 flags 0xc0800000
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: error unknown xrdp_sec_process_mcs_data tag 0xc006 size 8
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: error unknown xrdp_sec_process_mcs_data tag 0xc00a size 8
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_sec_out_mcs_data: using no security
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: keyboard_type [4] keyboard_subtype [0]
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_load_keyboard_layout: model [] variant [] layout [us] options []
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: [20201123-11:23:13] [INFO ] TLS connection established from 10.10.70.254 port 1113: TLSv1.2 with cipher ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_caps_process_order: bitmap cache v3 supported
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_caps_process_pointer: client supports new(color) cursor
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_caps_process_glyphcache: support level 3
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_process_offscreen_bmpcache: support level 1 cache size 5242880 MB cache entries 100
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_caps_process_surface_cmds:
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]:  cmdFlags 0x00000052
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_caps_process_frame_ack:
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]:  max_unacknowledged_frame_count 2
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_caps_process_codecs: nscodec, codec id 1, properties len 3
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_caps_process_codecs: unknown codec id 5
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_caps_process_codecs: RemoteFX, codec id 3, properties len 49
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: yeah, up_and_running
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_channel_drdynvc_start:
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp:xrdp_bitmap [4104192998]: xrdp_bitmap_create: noorders
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: [20201123-11:23:14] [DEBUG] xrdp_00003fa7_wm_login_mode_event_00000001
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp:xrdp_mm [4104193001]: xrdp_mm_create: bpp 16 mcs_connection_type 7 jpeg_codec_id 0 v3_codec_id 0 rfx_codec_id 3 h264_codec_id 0
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: [20201123-11:23:14] [INFO ] Cannot find keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00020409.ini
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: [20201123-11:23:14] [INFO ] Loading keymap file /etc/xrdp/km-00000409.ini
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: [20201123-11:23:14] [WARN ] local keymap file for 0x00020409 found and doesn't match built in keymap, using local keymap file
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_wm_login_mode_changed: login_mode is 0
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: in xrdp_wm_init:
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_wm_init: channel rdpdr channel id 0 is allowed
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_wm_init: channel rdpsnd channel id 1 is allowed
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_wm_init: channel cliprdr channel id 2 is allowed
Nov 23 11:23:14 localhost xrdp[3175]: xrdp_wm_init: channel nlr3hv channel id 3 is disabled
Nov 23 11:23:22 localhost Dicomizer[2654]: [Info] Scan watchfolder : /home/dicom/Watchfolder/
Nov 23 11:23:22 localhost Dicomizer[2654]: [Info] Scan watchfolder : /home/dicom/Watchfolder/
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: (3174)(139867984213824)[INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 48524
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp[16295]: (16295)(139693899400640)[INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: sesman connect ok
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: (3174)(139867984213824)[INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username root, ip 10.10.70.254:1113 - socket: 12
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: (3174)(139867984213824)[INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp[16295]: (16295)(139693899400640)[INFO ] xrdp_wm_log_msg: login successful for display 10
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[16299]: (16299)(139867984213824)[INFO ] calling auth_start_session from pid 16299
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost systemd-logind[2688]: New session c2 of user root.
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost systemd[1]: Started Session c2 of user root.
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[16301]: (16301)(139867984213824)[INFO ] Xvnc :10 -auth .Xauthority -geometry 3840x2160 -depth 16 -rfbauth /root/.vnc/sesman_passwd-root@localhost.localdomain:10 -bs -nolisten tcp -localhost -dpi 96
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: Xvnc TigerVNC 1.9.0 - built Nov  8 2019 23:18:11
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: Copyright (C) 1999-2018 TigerVNC Team and many others (see README.rst)
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: See http://www.tigervnc.org for information on TigerVNC.
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: Underlying X server release 12003000, The X.Org Foundation
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: Mon Nov 23 11:23:25 2020
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: vncext:      VNC extension running!
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: vncext:      Listening for VNC connections on local interface(s), port 5910
Nov 23 11:23:25 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: vncext:      created VNC server for screen 0
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: Mon Nov 23 11:23:26 2020
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: Connections: accepted: 127.0.0.1::56666
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[16299]: (16299)(139867984213824)[CORE ] waiting for window manager (pid 16300) to exit
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: SConnection: Client needs protocol version 3.3
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: VNCSConnST:  Server default pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: VNCSConnST:  Client pixel format depth 16 (16bpp) little-endian rgb565
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost dbus-daemon[4947]: [session uid=0 pid=4947] Activating via systemd: service name='org.a11y.Bus' unit='at-spi-dbus-bus.service' requested by ':1.4' (uid=0 pid=16457 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-check-accelerated " label="system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0")
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost systemd[4475]: Starting Accessibility services bus...
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost dbus-daemon[4947]: [session uid=0 pid=4947] Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.Bus'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost systemd[4475]: Started Accessibility services bus.
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost at-spi-bus-launcher[16474]: dbus-daemon[16479]: Activating service name='org.a11y.atspi.Registry' requested by ':1.0' (uid=0 pid=16457 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-check-accelerated " label="system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0")
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost dbus-daemon[4947]: [session uid=0 pid=4947] Activating via systemd: service name='org.gtk.vfs.Daemon' unit='gvfs-daemon.service' requested by ':1.6' (uid=0 pid=16457 comm="/usr/libexec/gnome-session-check-accelerated " label="system_u:system_r:unconfined_service_t:s0")
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost systemd[4475]: Starting Virtual filesystem service...
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost at-spi-bus-launcher[16474]: dbus-daemon[16479]: Successfully activated service 'org.a11y.atspi.Registry'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost at-spi-bus-launcher[16474]: SpiRegistry daemon is running with well-known name - org.a11y.atspi.Registry
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost dbus-daemon[4947]: [session uid=0 pid=4947] Successfully activated service 'org.gtk.vfs.Daemon'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost systemd[4475]: Started Virtual filesystem service.
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.Shell'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.Shell'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.A11ySettings'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Clipboard'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Color'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Datetime'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Housekeeping'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Keyboard'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.MediaKeys'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Mouse'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Power'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.PrintNotifications'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Rfkill'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.ScreensaverProxy'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sharing'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Smartcard'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Sound'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.Wacom'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: WARNING: Unable to find required component 'org.gnome.SettingsDaemon.XSettings'
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: Entering running state
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: Unable to init server: Could not connect: Connection refused
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost journal[16501]: Cannot open display:
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gvfsd[16485]: A connection to the bus can't be made
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session[16300]: gnome-session-binary[16300]: GLib-GIO-WARNING: Error releasing name org.gnome.SessionManager: The connection is closed
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost gnome-session-binary[16300]: GLib-GIO-WARNING: Error releasing name org.gnome.SessionManager: The connection is closed
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost systemd[4475]: Stopping D-Bus User Message Bus...
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[16299]: (16299)(139867984213824)[CORE ] window manager (pid 16300) did exit, cleaning up session
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[16299]: (16299)(139867984213824)[INFO ] calling auth_stop_session and auth_end from pid 16299
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost systemd[4475]: Stopped D-Bus User Message Bus.
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: Connections: closed: 127.0.0.1::56666 (Server shutdown)
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: EncodeManager: Framebuffer updates: 1
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: EncodeManager:   Raw:
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: EncodeManager:     Solid: 136 rects, 8.2944 Mpixels
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: EncodeManager:            15.8219 MiB (1:1 ratio)
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: EncodeManager:   Total: 136 rects, 8.2944 Mpixels
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: EncodeManager:          15.8219 MiB (1:1 ratio)
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: ComparingUpdateTracker: 0 pixels in / 0 pixels out
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: ComparingUpdateTracker: (1:-nan ratio)
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: (3174)(139867984213824)[INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username root, display :10.0, session_pid 16299, ip 10.10.70.254:1113 - socket: 12
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost systemd[4475]: Started D-Bus User Message Bus.
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost systemd-logind[2688]: Session c2 logged out. Waiting for processes to exit.
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: chansrv::main: using log file [/root/.local/share/xrdp/xrdp-chansrv.10.log]
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: [20201123-11:23:26] [CORE ] main: app started pid 16320(0x00003fc0)
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: [20201123-11:23:26] [INFO ] main: DISPLAY env var set to :10.0
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: [20201123-11:23:26] [INFO ] main: using DISPLAY 10
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: [20201123-11:23:26] [INFO ] channel_thread_loop: thread start
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: [20201123-11:23:26] [INFO ] Socket 12: AF_UNIX connection received
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: process_message_channel_setup: chan name 'rdpdr' id 0 flags 00000000
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: process_message_channel_setup: chan name 'rdpsnd' id 1 flags 00000000
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: process_message_channel_setup: chan name 'cliprdr' id 2 flags 00000000
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: process_message_channel_setup: chan name 'nlr3hv' id 3 flags 00000000
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: process_message_channel_setup: chan name 'nlw3hv' id 4 flags 00000000
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: process_message_channel_setup: chan name 'drdynvc' id 5 flags 00000000
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204839]: xcommon_init: connected to display ok
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204839]: sound_init:
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204839]: audin_init:
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]: sound_process_output_format:
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       wFormatTag      1
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       nChannels       2
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       nSamplesPerSec  44100
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       nAvgBytesPerSec 176400
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       nBlockAlign     4
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       wBitsPerSample  16
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       cbSize          0
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]: sound_process_output_format:
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       wFormatTag      1
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       nChannels       2
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       nSamplesPerSec  22050
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       nAvgBytesPerSec 88200
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       nBlockAlign     4
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       wBitsPerSample  16
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104204931]:       cbSize          0
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104205032]: sound_process_training: round trip time 101
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: xrdp-chansrv [4104205048]: scard_init:
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: chansrv:smartcard_pcsc [4104205048]: scard_pcsc_init:
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: chansrv:smartcard_pcsc [4104205048]: scard_pcsc_init: g_remove_dir failed
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: [20201123-11:23:26] [INFO ] term_signal_handler: got signal 15
Nov 23 11:23:26 localhost xrdp-sesman[3174]: [20201123-11:23:26] [INFO ] xserver_fatal_handler: entered.......
Nov 23 11:23:36 localhost systemd-logind[2688]: Removed session c2.
```

Comment: What is the exact error message you get? What error messages do you get in the log files on the server?

Comment: I've added the log lines to the post